# Python Django:JSONDecodeError when i try to retrieve data from the api

Tags: django, python-requests

When I tried to return a date in my python api request, I get the error message 'Object of type date is not JSON serializable'. I converted it to JSON using this function below:

```
    def myconverter(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()
```

Now it is returning a null value and also the error message .

> 'JSONDecodeError at /search/
>       Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

What am i doing wrongly?This is my code below:

```
    new_parameter=json.dumps(parameters, default = myconverter)
    print(new_parameter)

    urls = 'https://ije-api.tcore.xyz/v1/flight/search-flight'

    result = requests.post(urls,json=new_parameter,headers=headers).json()
            print(result.text)

    flight ={
                "departure_date": result['body']['data']['itineraries'][0]['origin_destinations'][0]['segments'][0]['departure']['date'],
                "departure_time": result['body']['data']['itineraries'][0]['origin_destinations'][0]['segments'][0]['departure']['time'], 



            }
     print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a custom encoder by creating a subclass of [`json.JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder), you need to return/call `super` of the [`default`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default) method to encode regular JSON serializable objects

```
class DatetimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
            return o.isoformat()
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

new_parameter=json.dumps(parameters, cls=DatetimeEncoder)
```

Comment: @lain. I am still getting 'JSONDecodeError at /search/ Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'